# How to solve Forbidden access error in graphql on my strapi custom plugin?

Tags: graphql, strapi

I have created a strapi custom plugin and a content type defined as follows:

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "targetcontents",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "targetcontent",
    "pluralName": "targetcontents",
    "displayName": "targetcontent"
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": true,
    "comment": ""
  },
  "attributes": {
    "contentname": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "contentdescription": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

The routes,controllers and services are all boilerplate:

```
export default factories.createCoreRouter('plugin::targetplugin.targetcontent');
export default factories.createCoreController('plugin::targetplugin.targetcontent');
export default factories.createCoreService('plugin::targetplugin.targetcontent');
```

I have a single entry in the database for this contenttype:

[image]

When I run the graphql query:

```
query
{
  targetpluginTargetcontents {
    data {
      id
      attributes {
        contentname
        contentdescription
        createdAt
        updatedAt
        publishedAt
      }
    }
    meta {
      pagination {
        total
        page
        pageSize
        pageCount
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error in return:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Forbidden access",
      "extensions": {
        "error": {
          "name": "ForbiddenError",
          "message": "Forbidden access",
          "details": {}
        },
        "code": "FORBIDDEN"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "targetpluginTargetcontents": null
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain how I can overcome this?

Thanks

Normally I would have gone into:

Settings->Users & Permissions->Roles and modified the permissions there, but for plugin contenttypes, this does not show up.

[image]